Did I write the locks properly to prevent concurrency issues?
There may be a dozen things that could be improved about this code, but it's just a very quick proof of concept and for the sake of this post I'm specifically wanting to know if someone can verify whether I took the locks properly such that concurrent processes couldn't get the ReferenceCount out of whack.
public class Engagement { /* ... This is just a simple DTO ... */ }

static Dictionary<string, CachedEngagement> engagementCache = [];

public class CachedEngagement(Engagement engagement)
{
    public Engagement Engagement { get; set; } = engagement;
    public int ReferenceCount { get; set; } = 1;
}

public void UsingEngagement(string engagementId, Action<Engagement> action)
{
    // I understand locking on strings is discouraged. Just doing it here
    // to keep this example code short and sweet.
    string lockString = "engagement-lock-" + engagementId;

    try
    {
        lock (lockString)
        {
            if (engagementCache.TryGetValue(engagementId, out CachedEngagement value))
                value.ReferenceCount++;
            else
                engagementCache.Add(engagementId, new CachedEngagement(GetEngagement(engagementId)));
        }

        action(engagementCache[engagementId].Engagement);
    }
    finally
    {
        SetEngagement(engagementId, engagementCache[engagementId].Engagement);
        
        lock (lockString)
        {
            if (--engagementCache[engagementId].ReferenceCount == 0)
                engagementCache.Remove(engagementId);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
// UsingEngagement("123", e => e.SomeProperty = "456"

So the idea is to let all processes needing to use a particular engagement share a reference to the same one rather than each reading their own copy. The engagement would be persisted (SetEngagement()) as each process completes but the engagement is only ever read (GetEngagement()) once for all concurrently running processes. When concurrently running processes are all complete, then the item is removed from the cache.

So you want to key-based locking if I'm understanding correctly? There are libraries that do that, I happen to have written one myself.

Rather than add a second version, it would be better to ask a follow up question with a link back to this one. Each post should a question with answers, not a discussion. Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. What to do after the question has been answered.

Setting aside the string-based "lock"—which is unlikely to provide mutual exclusion because the concatenated strings with the same text may not be the same string object—using a Dictionary here is not safe.
Different threads can enter the lock with different lock objects and modify the dictionary concurrently. Per its documentation, Dictionary does not support writes occurring concurrently with reads or other writes. This may lead to crashes, infinite loops, or incorrect results (such as duplicate entries) that would break your reference counting mechanism.
If you need a dictionary that supports this kind of concurrent access, consider ConcurrentDictionary.
Regarding the challenge of creating different locks, consider using a more coarse-grained lock if possible for your performance requirements. This will be much clearer and more reliable.

Note: I focused on the cache's reference counting as requested in the question, but sharing these Engagement objects across threads requires all the actions and SetEngagement to be able to deal with concurrent modification by other actions. This may significantly increase the amount of code that needs to be aware of concurrency.

So it sounds like my options would be to either use a single lock object for everything, or to use ConcurrentDictionary. Is that accurate?

Just FYI, did some tests and I'm convinced locking on strings this way is not a problem in and of itself. "123" + "456" yields the same hash code as "12345" + "6", for example. And further reading suggests that the only reason it's discouraged is that if you write a library then you may potentially choose a string value that consuming code (or other dependencies) may also lock on. So... I could be wrong, but I'm not convinced it's that big of a deal.

In regard to SetEngagement, this may be a special case (or maybe not, hoping you'll tell me) where I think the problem is mitigated by the fact that concurrent processes would only update different properties... there would never be concurrent changes to the same property of an object.

@BVernon FYI, String.GetHashCode does actually hash the string content, it does not guarantee that it points to the same reference.

@BVernon simple example illustrating that with your code you'll likely never lock the same object https://onecompiler.com/csharp/42pmkqbrx

@JensV Good point. Oh well. :)

@BVernon You need both the dictionary to be accessed thread-safely and the per-Engagement locks need to be fixed. Switching to ConcurrentDictionary will solve only the first part, the focus of the original question. To fix the lock management too, a single shared lock is the simplest option. (Though there are possible tricks involving ConcurrentDictionary and Interlocked.CompareExchange, it is much harder to be sure that they are correct.)

@BVernon (to your 3rd comment) The actions might be alright if they examine and change only one property, but you still need to consider whether SetEngagement calls for one object are safe for concurrency with GetEngagement, other SetEngagement calls, and the modifications done by actions. In general, mutable objects should not be concurrently accessed unless all code using them is aware of and designed for this.

ConcurrentDictionary would be superfluous if the calls to the Dictionary happen within a mutual exclusion lock which MIGHT be what @BVernon intends to do. Currently there is zero locking happening, just overhead.

@JensV FYI, just did a test with .Equals() and object.ReferenceEquals() and both indicate the strings are the same. Unless you've experienced a contradicting scenario, I would be inclined to believe using strings the way I have used them should be fine.
